# Does a map which preserve harmonic forms preserve co-closed forms (locally)?

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, riemannian-geometry, differential-forms

$\newcommand{\M}{\mathcal{M}}$
$\newcommand{\N}{\mathcal{N}}$

This is a follow-up of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2763249/does-a-map-which-preserve-harmonic-forms-preserve-co-closedness-of-forms).

Let $\M,\N$ be closed $d$-dimensional oriented Riemannian manifolds ($d \ge 2$). Let $f:\M \to \N$ be smooth, and let $\delta=d^*$ be the adjoint of the exterior derivative. Recall a form $\omega$ is called *co-closed* if $\delta \omega=0$.

Let  $1 \le k \le d-1$ be *fixed*. Consider the following two properties $f$ can have: For *every* open $U \subseteq \N$,

1. $\omega\in \Omega^k(U)$ is co-closed $\Rightarrow f^*\omega$ is co-closed.

$\,\,\,\,$ 2. $\omega\in \Omega^k(U)$ is closed and co-closed $\Rightarrow f^*\omega$ is closed and co-closed.

> **Question:**   Does property 2 implies property 1?

(Property 1 implies property 2, since closed forms are automatically preserved by all maps).

The point is that *locally*, [the space of closed and co-closed forms is infinite-dimensional](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2790343/104576). Thus property $2$ gives us a "infinite-dimensional amount" of information about $f$, so maybe there is a chance the answer is positive.

**Edit:**

Here are some examples for non-isometric maps which satisfy property $(1)$. Let $d$ be even, and set $k=\frac{d}{2}$. Then, every conformal map satisfies property $(1)$. Indeed, if $f$ is conformal, then for every $k$-form $\omega$ on $\N$,

$$\delta \omega=0 \Rightarrow \delta(|\det df|^{1-2\frac{k}{d}} f^*\omega)=0.$$

This essentially follows from the fact $f^*(\star \omega)= |\det df|^{1-2\frac{k}{d}} \star f^*\omega$, which implies
$$ d(|\det df|^{1-2\frac{k}{d}} \star f^*\omega)=df^*(\star \omega)=f^* d(\star \omega)=0. $$

Putting $k=\frac{d}{2}$ we get the desired property.

Of course, another natural question is whether or not all maps which satisfy $(1)$ are conformal.

Comment: Do you have an example of 1. that's not a local isometry?

Comment: Yes, conformal maps sometimes satisfy it. I have added an explanation about this.